# Bash - IF Syntax

Tags: bash

I am running this line of code:

```
until ([ "$completed" == "$started" ] && [ "$completed" == "$total" ] && [ "$total" == "$started" ] && [ "$completed" -gt 0 ] && [ "$started" -gt 0 ] && [ "$total" -gt 0 ]) || [ "$totalerrors" -gt 0 ]; do
```

But I am getting the error of `line 25: [: : integer expression expected`

What is the correct syntax for the OR section?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run it with `set -x` to see which `[` looks wrong (my guess is one of the variables is not an integer)? (And why does the title say ‘IF[sic] Syntax’; there's no `if` in there?)

Comment: Btw, in `[ "$completed" == "$started" ] && [ "$completed" == "$total" ] && [ "$total" == "$started" ]` the last comparison is useless, if A == B & A == C then B is equal to C

Answer (score 4):

```
until ([ "$completed" == "$started" ] &&
       [ "$completed" == "$total" ] &&
       [ "$total" == "$started" ] &&
       [ "$completed" -gt 0 ] &&
       [ "$started" -gt 0 ] &&
       [ "$total" -gt 0 ]) ||
       [ "$totalerrors" -gt 0 ]; do
```

Your code looks OK. Probably, one of the variables you are checking is not set, so you end up with a call that looks like `[ "" -gt 0`]. A few suggestions:

1. Don't use `==` with `[`. Either use `=` (the correct operator) or switch to `[[ ... == ... ]]`.
2. Don't use `=` to compare integers; use `-eq`. (For example, `[ 03 = 3 ]` fails, while `[ 03 -eq 3 ]` succeeds.)
3. Use `{ ... }` instead of `( ... )` to group your tests. Parentheses start an unnecessary subshell. Note that the final command in `{ ... }` must be terminated by a `;`.
4. Use `[[`, which provides `&&` and `||` with the correct precedence.

   ```
   [[ $completed == $started && ... && $total -gt 0 || $totalerrors -gt 0 ]]
   ```